# How to manually create a boost ptree?

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I've been using boost libraries to parse XML files and I have to create a ptree manually. I need to add several children with the same tag name to the ptree. I've tried with put, add_child and put_child, but I can't make it. 
The ptree that I need to create should be like the one presented below (xml representation):

```
<onexit>
    <assign location="test1"></assign>
    <assign location="test2"></assign>
    <assign location="test3"></assign>
</onexit>
```

What do I need to do?